# Squid is not returning http message body on debug

Tags: squid

According to [Squid documentation](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/KnowledgeBase/DebugSections), when `debug_options rotate=1 ALL,9` is set in `squid.conf`, I should see `HTTP Message Body` in `cache.log`

However, it's not showing up.

I do see, everything, including HTTP headers, but not the body.

I even tried to set `debug_options` to `11,9`, but I only see HTTP headers, not the body.

Squid is configured as transparent proxy for both HTTP and HTTPS.
The request I'm sending is HTTPS.

Anyone, please help?

Submitted bug: https://bugs.squid-cache.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5194

Comment: Didn't find any traces of this statements in the article. What makes you think you should see the body on level 9 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The bug has been fixed (incorrect documentation reference has been removed):

https://bugs.squid-cache.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5194